# Converting List[String] to String with quote in Scala

Tags: scala

Is there an easy way to convert List[String] to String format with `"` and `,`. For example

```
val fruits: List[String] = List("Apple", "Banana", "Grapes", "Pears")
==> "Apple", "Banana", "Grapes", "Pears"
```

I want to do this because I have to append the result in JSON string.

```
{
 ....,
 "fruits": ["Apple", "Banana", "Grapes", "Pears"],
 ....
}
```

Comment: `s""""${fruits.makeString(", ")}""""` But what if some of the values contain double quotes? Crafting json "by hand" is actually, suprisingly harder than it looks.
So, better, do something standard, like `Jackson.mapper.writeValueAsString(fruits)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
fruits.mkString("\"fruits\": [\"", "\",\"", "\"]")
```

but I'd use something like https://github.com/circe/circe instead of building JSONs myself

Comment: It fails if strings in fruits have quotes.

Comment: As dima mentioned in the comments - it is hard to wrangle your own JSON. That's why I suggested using a library that does that for you like Circe

Comment: I will be glad to remove my comment as soon as the answer will describe the reason for using libraries. From my point of view the answer has to warn users about possible problems too.